# Постановка тире в середине предложения

Tags: пунктуация

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: есть предложение, звучит так:

*Я подошёл к телевизору и включил его на пустой канал - белая рябь на максимуме децибелов прекрасная колыбельная для засыпающего человека...*

Почему нет тире после "децибелов", перед "прекрасная колыбель"? Или это ошибка/опечатка? Кстати, правильно ли я поставил двоеточие в начале?

Дополнительно:

Я не уверен, что мне позволяют дать больше контекста авторские права на книгу "Страх и отвращение в Лас-Вегасе" Хантера Томпсона в переводе на русский язык А. Керви, поэтому я немного заменю слова в тексте, но оставлю смысл написанного.

В квартире никого не было. Я подошёл к телевизору и включил его на пустой канал(действие происходит в 1971) - белая рябь на максимуме децибел прекрасная колыбельная для засыпающего человека, сильное, отрывистое шипение, заглушающее все живое и обыденное.

Первая часть второго предложения(как раз о которой у меня вопрос) не изменена.

Comment: Телевозор можно **переключить** на другой канал или просто **включить**. "Включил его на пустой канал" не верно как грамматически, так и  технически: включая телевизор, вы не знаете, на какой канал он настроен.

Comment: @М_Г, не знаю, как в России, но у нас в Армении сейчас при  включении т/в повляется сперва  пустой канал.Так что ошибки не вижу.

Comment: @М_Г, я бы с Вами и согласился, но так написано в исходном предложении. Может, стоит делать поправку на то, что действие происходит в 1971?

Comment: Не будем рассматривать техническую сторону. Но грамматически не могу принять "включил на пустой канал". Допустимо: "включил на пустом канале".

Comment: Нашел версию, в которой все знаки на месте: http://www.litmir.me/br/?b=27751&ShowDeleted=1&p=13

Comment: @М_Г, получается, в печатной версии всё же опечатка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тире может быть и в начале и даже в конце - при переходе от стихов ("столбиком") к прозе.

Отсутствие его в Вашем примере ошибка (не опечатка).

Автора предложения смутило два тире весьма близко одно от другого, вот он и опустил второе, обязательное. А вот первое тире легко заменимо на двоеточие:

*Я подошёл к телевизору и включил его на пустой канал: белая рябь на максимуме децибелов - прекрасная колыбельная для засыпающего человека...*

У Вас с двоеточиями "в начале" перебор того же происхождения, что и нехватка тире (между подлежащим и сказуемым): как автору не захотелось "украшать" предложение двумя тире, так Вы умудрились в одной недлинной строке разместить два двоеточия,

а надо бы:

*Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Есть предложение, звучит так:*

Answer (score 4):

Ещё один вариант для оформления предложения:

**Я подошёл к телевизору и включил его на пустой канал ― белая рябь на максимуме децибелов, прекрасная колыбельная для засыпающего человека...**

Быстрый эффект от включения телевизора лучше обозначить тире. А далее следует перечень увиденного и размышления по этому поводу.

Comment: Действительно, появилась динамика. А вот что вы думаете по поводу правильности выражения "включил на канал"?

Comment: А имелся ли в виду этот "быстрый эффект" у автора? Я что-то совсем не уверен. Но если так, то я бы согласился. Согласится ли автор...

Comment: Автор  поставил первое тире, мне кажется, что оно на месте. А дальше стоит задача: делить  предложение паузами на три части или на две. В первом случае предложение плохо читается, поэтому лучше остановиться на варианте с двумя частями, объединив два последних предложения (между ними запятая) .  И по поводу "включил на пустой канал".  Если телевизор был выключен "на пустом канале", то он на нем и включится. Может быть, лучше "включил  на пустом канале", то есть оно не выбирал, что включает.

Comment: "Включил на пустом канале" - приемлемый компромисс, по-моему :))

Comment: @ Arina, а если он все-таки знал, что включает пустой канал?

Comment: Может, и знал, специально включил себе "колыбельную". Кстати, в Сети есть эта книга, и вот что в ней: "Но иногда… трудно приспособиться к дыханию большого города, где ночь полна всевозможных звуков.... Машины, гудки, шаги… невозможно расслабиться, так что глуши всю эту лажу успокаивающим шипением пустой картинки одуревшего телевизора. Заблокируй переключатель каналов, и дремли себе в удовольствие".  Так что, наверное, включал  пустой канал постоянно.

Answer (score 0):

По сути: **Это не ошибка**. Тире между подлежащим и сказуемым (видимо так надо трактовать желание его поставить) было бы, пожалуй, необходимо, если бы фраза этим и ограничивалась.

Но у Розенталя ("СПРАВОЧНИК ПО ПРАВОПИСАНИЮ, ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЮ, ЛИТЕРАТУРНОМУ РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЮ") есть формулировка достаточно веского основания не ставить такое тире, если не хочется.

> Тире обычно не ставится, хотя подлежащее и сказуемое выражены
>   именительным падежом существительного:
>
> в простых по составу предложениях разговорного стиля речи,
>   например: Моя сестра студентка;

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/42.htm
Почему не хочется - это уже отдельный разговор, см. ниже.

.---------
Теперь подробно.

Я работаю с исходной формулировкой вопроса, правку считаю здесь неуместной, ибо автор лучше знает *с какой именно фразой он столкнулся* - а вопрос стоит именно по этой фразе. Насколько сама фраза правильная, надо обсуждать в ответах.

Итак:

*"Я подошёл к телевизору и включил его на пустой канал - белая рябь на максимуме децибел прекрасная колыбельная для засыпающего человека..."*

Есть такое хорошее необязательное правило у редакторов. *Двух тире в одной фразе не должно быть.* Сразу скажу, что слышал его только изустно, поэтому ссылки дать не могу, но оно вполне разумно. К сожалению, его иногда понимают буквально, что приводит к недоразумениям, но реально речь идёт о двух тире, одно из которых ставится по мотивам периода и/или разделения бессоюзного сложного, то есть по мотивам §169 и §171 правил русского языка, а второе зрительно воспринимается не по структуре фразы и его можно по тем или иным мотивам опустить.

.=========
§ 169. Тире ставится между двумя сказуемыми и между двумя независимыми предложениями, если во втором из них содержится неожиданное присоединение или резкое противопоставление по отношению к первому, например:
Я вышел, не желая его обидеть, на террасу – и обомлел.
Герцен
Я спешу туда ж – а там уже весь город.
Пушкин
Хотел объехать целый свет – и не объехал сотой доли.
Грибоедов
Хотел рисовать – кисти выпадали из рук. Пробовал читать – взоры его скользили над строками. 
Лермонтов
....

§ 171. Тире ставится между предложениями, не соединенными посредством союзов, если второе предложение заключает в себе результат или вывод из того, о чем говорится в первом, например:
Хвалы приманчивы – как их не пожелать?
Крылов
Солнце взошло – начинается день.*
.=========
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/158-tire

Возможно еще другие параграфы, 170-й, например, но ни о них речь. По этим мотивам поставлено первое тире (хотя и не очевидно, что оно там неизбежно). А вот по каким мотивам должно стоять второе тире.

Я вижу только один выход выход, если по мнению редактора знак после "децибел(ов)" необходим, и тут я согласен с Galina Avanesova.

***Я подошёл к телевизору и включил его на пустой канал: белая рябь на максимуме децибел - прекрасная колыбельная для засыпающего человека...***

Но я категорически не считаю это простой правкой, здесь появляется иной смысл, направленность действия по включению "пустого" канала, без воли автора такое нельзя делать. Должен быть подходящий контекст.

По поводу децибелов и включения.
"Децибел" - это счетная форма. Как пять вольт или сто грамм. Можно сколько угодно отстаивать правильность "пяти помидоров" (а не помидор), но по отношению к единицам измерения, физическим - особенно, да в разговорной речи  это уже будет полнейшим ретроградством.

"Включил канал" - а почему нет-то? Я опускаю техническую сторону, что там где у кого "включается" при первом включении телевизора, это не от Армении зависит, а от телевизора в лучшем случае или от того, насколько кривые руки у того, кто настраивал. При этом человек явно не имеет пульта - или не умеет им пользоваться, коли подходит к телевизору, чтобы что-то там "переключить". Вот некая аналогия. Вы **включаете** ближний свет фар - или **переключаете** на него с дальнего? Боюсь, что придираться к "включил"/"переключил" - это уже какой-то неумный пуризм. То же и с телевизором.

Я думаю, что "включил [на канал]" здесь работает как универсальное слово, если неизвестно, был ли телевизор включен ранее. Не вижу причин для войны и ломки копий.

*(если понадобится вычитка и правка, сделаю позже, вынужден прерваться.)*